# Where 2 insert closing tag in database display?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that's styled to display a question followed by several answer choices, with the question and each answer wrapped in a div, like this...

```
<div>Question</div>
<div>Answer A</div>
<div>Answer B</div>
<div>Answer C</div>
```

However, I'd like the entire thing to be wrapped in an outer div (or section, actually), like this...

```
<section class="OuterWrapper">
  <div>Question</div>
  <div>Answer A</div>
  <div>Answer B</div>
  <div>Answer C</div>
</section>
```

The problem is that if I insert the closing tag just after the answers (just before the last curly bracket), it displays a closing tag after every answer instead of a single closing tag. But if I insert the closing tag at the very end, then it displays just once PER PAGE. **Since I'm displaying multiple questions on a page, I need a closing tag for each question-and-answer group.**

Is there a way to achieve my goal, or do I need to scrap my entire script and replace it with something else?

```
$Q1 = null;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
$QID = $row['QID'];
$URL = $row['URL'];
$Value = $row['Value'];
$Question = $row['Question'];
$Answer = $row['Answer'];
$Correct = $row['Correct'];
$Correct = str_replace('1', 'correct', $Correct);
$Correct = str_replace('2', 'wrong', $Correct);

$Q2 = '  <form action="" method="post" id="quiz">
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">'.$Question.'</div>';

if ($row["Question"] != $Q1) {
$Q1 = $row["Question"];
echo "{$Q2}\n";
}

echo '<div class="Answer '.$Correct.'"><input type="radio" name="'.$QID.'" id="quiz"    value="'.$Value.'" /> '.$Answer.'</div>' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This may be over kill but you could use count for the total number in the array and then just if the first add the html if last add the html

Comment: Can you show me what that would look like? I've never used "count." Also, my data isn't in an array (as far as I know).

Comment: we use section when we want separate elements (this same category or similar). First tag inside section should be header (h). Example: one page in newspaper is a section, article is article and on a top this side we have header. More information you can find on this webpage html5doctor.com/the-section-element

Comment: OK, if I can't use the section element, then I'll use a div. But my overall goal is to simply wrap each question-and-answer set inside a "wrapper." It will help me style and manage the content considerably.

Comment: It appears that you're storing the last question and checking if it changed in the loop `if ($row["Question"] != $Q1)`, so you should be able to close and reopen the tag there: `echo "</div><div>{$Q2}\n";`  So, open a `<div>` before you begin the `fetch()` loop, allow it to close/open inside that `echo`, then terminate with a final `</div>` after the entire loop.

Comment: Where were you intending to close those `<form>` tags which are opened with each new question? Wherever you close those is probably where to close and reopen the containing `<div>` or `<section>`.

Comment: Hmmm...I must have modified my script, as I only have one form tag (and a matching closing tag at the end.) In the meantime, your previous comment is the correct answer to the question I asked above. (I wind up with an extra empty div at the beginning of my script, but I can easily deal with that.) I'll mark your response as the correct answer if you want to put your question in the "Correct Answer" format.